# how to design query for select price where sum(tax) less than price in to different table (tableA,tableB)

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2012

how to design query for select **price** where sum(tax) less than price in to different table (tableA,tableB)

Comment: Look for `HAVING` clause.

Comment: help me for design query

Comment: Did you try anything, This is very basic question

Comment: Show what have you tried for this homework, we are not going to do it for you.

Comment: Hello, welcome to SO.  Unfortunately, this question needs some editing before it meets the community's standards: The table shown as an image should instead be included as text (use code formatting to preserve the column layout).  It may also be helpful for your question to show a sample of the output that the query should produce.  You will find an "edit" link that you can use to make these or any other changes to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check following SQL Select statement

```
;with cte as (
    select 
        a.id, a.tax, a.idprice, b.price, 
        sum(tax) over (partition by a.idprice) sum_tax
    from tableA a
    inner join tableB b
    on a.idprice = b.idprice
)
select * from cte
where sum_tax < price
```

First of all I used a [SQL CTE (Common Table Expression) query](http://www.kodyaz.com/articles/article.aspx?articleid=18)
I used the CTE because I used the summed column in the WHERE clause.
You can also place the same SELECT statement in a sub-query instead of SQL CTE expression

One interesting thing about above query, maybe you see it for the first time; I use SUM() aggregate function with Partition By clause
Just like [SQL Count() Over (Partition By)](http://www.kodyaz.com/t-sql/sql-count-function-with-partition-by-clause.aspx) clause, partition by enables you to apply aggregate function over the rows sharing the same values

Comment: thank you , but I can group by idprice , idprice is not repetition

Comment: please don't encourage bad questions, instead, work with OP to fix the post and then reward with answer, answering LQ posts is bad for the site.